# Magento 2 Override image problem (static image of parent theme)

Tags: theme, overrides, magento2.2, parent-child-theme

Having a parent theme, I have created a child theme. (Magento 2.2)

Parent theme: `Mgs/claue`

Child theme: `Bee/elag`

In the web there is a `Title of page` with a background css:

```
.page-title-wrapper {
background-color: #f7f7f7;
padding: 58px 0 55px;
text-align: center;
background-image: url('../images/shop-category.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
position: relative;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: scroll;}
```

The image url shown is:

```
https://domain.tld/pub/static/version1508230959/frontend/Bee/elag/es_ES/images/shop-category.jpg
```

The background image is in:

```
/app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/web/images/shop-category.jpg
```

I have added the image that I want to replace in:

```
/app/design/frontend/Bee/elag/web/images/shop-category.jpg
```

It does not work, it isn't replaced, I have deleted cache but nothing.

What can happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is solved by changing the environment to development:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Comment: Thanks. What is pretty strange - i have to set this on each image change. So this mode do some further jobs